# php timestamp is too big?

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm currently grabbing a timestamp from an external API and it's returning **1380812164888** what's it doing to return such great value and how can I solve it so it's the correct `time()` format?

I also thought about doing `$array['timestamp']/1000` but then it returns **1380812164.89** which is obviously an invalid timestamp

Comment: No way to know without seeing far more info: what API? What does the FULL returned response look like? What format is the date expected to be? Etc.

Comment: Looks like a timestamp in milliseconds. Divide it by 1000.

Comment: what's wrong with 1380812164.89?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Divide it and then round to the nearest integer:

```
round($array['timestamp']/1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a timestamp with milliseconds. You can simply divide by a thousand and drop everything after the decimal like this:

```
$timestamp=floor($array['timestamp']/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to return the format you want?

Comment: Not correct.  It's already an alleged timestamp, and it's clearly way too large.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timestamp in milliseconds. Try this:

```
$msts = 1380812164888;
$ms = $msts/1000;
echo date("d M Y",$ms); // 03 Oct 2013
```

If you need a Unix timestamp in seconds:

```
$tstamp = round($msts/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 13 digit timestamp is nothing but `microtime()`.

Try this code to convert `microtime()` to `date()`

```
<?php
$updated='1380812164888';
@$nUpdated = date("l jS F \@ g:i a",$updated);
echo $nUpdated;

OUTPUT:
Wednesday 3rd June 5:27 pm
```